# Get package name in NativeScript android app?

Tags: android, nativescript

I want the package name of the app in my NativeScript app like you can in native android. I tried this code

```
const utilityModule = require("utils/utils");
console.log(utilityModule.getPackageName());
```

and got the error `utilityModule.getPackageName is not a function`. THis was based on the [code I found here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/ec24c5a96f9c1f51a3b3da1a893555a641109abf/tns-core-modules/utils/utils.android.ts#L87). Don't know why it didn't work. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at nativescript-appversion, which has a single API for x-platform access to the packagename.

Comment: Is it the `getAppId()` function?

Comment: Yes it is (I was on mobile while posting my message so it was a bit brief).

Comment: No problem. Thanks